# In an 'if' statement, is there a way to separate conditions with an OR instead of using elseif's?

Tags: python

So in python, if I want to make an if statement I need to do something like this (where a,b,c are conditions):

```
if(a) 
    x=1
elsif(b)
    x=1
elseif(c)
    x=1
```

is there a way to simply do something like:

```
if(a or b or c)
    x=1
```

this would save a huge amount of time, but it doesn't evaluate.

Comment: you don't need the parens in python. `if a:` is the preferred style

Comment: Whats wrong with `if a or b or c: x=1`

Comment: Did you try it? If you did, you'd see it works.

Comment: This is /highly/ dependent on the data and conditions you're working with. You'd need to elaborate further.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
if a or b or c:
    x=1
```

The only thing you are doing wrong is the syntax (no parens, use ":").  If thats not the problem maybe post the error you are getting or be a little more specific with your code.

Comment: OP did mention `a`, `b` and `c` are conditions. More details are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and here is an example:

```
num = 2

if num == 2 or num == 3:
    print(num)
```

The key to an or statement in Python is that you simply have to put the other condition after the or statement. My mistake when I first began was by saying "if condition 1 or if condition to". You don't need to put an if statement twice, but simply 1 time, and then after or your second condition. So yes, with this syntax, you can perform an or statement, or multiple or statements. For example:

```
if num == 2 or num == 3 or num == 4:
         print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=False
b=True
c=True
x=0
if any([a,b,c]):
   x=1
print(x)
```

Or:

```
print(int(any([a,b,c])))
```

Comment: I would even go further: `x = 1 if any([a,b,c]) else 0`

Comment: Or, even further: `x = int(any([a,b,c]))`

Comment: It's important to point out that `any` will *evaluate all* of the conditions while`elseif` or  `or` approaches will short circuit return once a True-ish value is found.  Not usually an issue, but important to know about when it is.